# Extracting BIOS Files from Acer's self extracting executable

Tags: laptop, bios, acer-aspire

Acer's self extracting executable for updating my bios is not opening at all.
Even in task manager, it stays on for one second and then disappears. This used to work previously on Windows 10. The last time I used this was about 8 months ago.

[Here](https://global-download.acer.com/GDFiles/BIOS/BIOS/BIOS_Acer_1.08_A_A.zip?acerid=635834268356699552&Step1=NOTEBOOK&Step2=ASPIRE&Step3=ASPIRE%20E5-522G&OS=ALL&LC=en&BC=ACER&SC=PA_6) is the link to the executable.

How can I run this/extract the important files from inside?

My Machine is [Acer Aspire E5-522G](https://www.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/support-product/6004?b=1)

Answer (score 0):

Self extracting executables contains a Zip/Rar/7zip/whatever -archive within that file.

Open the executable file as if it was an archive, using one of the archivers and  you will usually be able to access the files.

There is usually a file named "README", "INSTRUCTIONS" or similar.
Read the instructions and follow them *EXACTLY*, failure to to do so is likely to cause failures and/or problems.

If GUI-driven software fails, try launching it from the command prompt, after an initial 'CD' into the directory/folder that contains the software and related files.
This may well display any messages or codes that can be used for fault analysis; allowing to remedy the problem.

There might also be an option to move the firmware (BIOS) onto a USB-stick, place that in a special USB-connector and press a "update-bios-button" (present at least on some ASUS MB's) - once again; Read the instructions, also technical documents on the MB may contain important detail.

Comment: So, I tried using 7zip "Open as archive > 7z", and I was able to extract the files. Now when I run the required executable, it says, there is no ROM file in the folder!
See [Here](https://gyazo.com/cb6d1cb9e5e8e543ce60e7510ae5ec72)

Comment: updated text above.